# Meaning of "release" in "A complete release of X by each entrant"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading the [Facebook Promotions guidelines](https://www.facebook.com/page_guidelines.php#promotionsguidelines) and I don't understand the meaning of "release" in this sentence:

> Promotions on Facebook must include the following:
>   - A complete release of Facebook by each entrant or participant.

It is not about a software release, right?

Does it mean that each entrant has to say "*I understand that Facebook is not responsible for this*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very poor wording on their part, in my opinion. But it's legalese, so using hard-to-understand jargon isn't really surprising.  Contextually, it seems like you're most likely correct—it's unlikely to be about a software release.  But I wouldn't normally expect the "release" bit to be phrased this way in English.

---

When I clicked your link, because my browser is set to Japanese, I was presented with the Japanese version of the Facebook agreement.  Since I know you read Japanese, I thought I'd bring it up in a comment, and I'm posting it as an answer because you asked me to.

Here's the relevant portion:

> 2. Facebook上でのプロモーションには、以下を含める必要があります。
>   　　　a. 応募者または参加者によるFacebookの**完全な責任免除**。

This seems to confirm that your interpretation is correct.

Comment: For non-Japanese speakers, that translates to: `Entrants and participants discharge Facebook from any kind of responsibility`

Answer (score 2):

*Does it mean that each entrant has to say "I understand that Facebook is not responsible for this"?*

Yes. I think it literally means release of liability.

Answer (score -1):

Very ambiguous.

And yes, it does mean that Facebook holds no responsibility for whatever is there under promotion --sort of a disclaimer.

Check [this blog](http://bloggylaw.com/facebook-promotion-guidelines/) that further tells how to do *that.* -

> The easiest way to do this? Include a statement along the lines of, “By entering this contest, you agree to a complete [release *(n. #2)*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/RELEASE) of Facebook from any or all liability in connection with this contest.”

Example of GumTree South Africa (Check #5):

[image]